# Way to tackle arbitrage bots

Tags: pancakeswap, liquidity-provider, flashbots

I deployed a token ABC and created a liquidity pool in pancakeswap with pair ABC/BNB. But arbitraged bots attacked and stole a large sum of money. How to stop this and why is this occurring?
I think something gets arbitraged away when there is difference in price in different exchanges, but I have created pool in 1 exchange only.

Comment: Maybe you could reference your pair creation tx so that we could help you better with investigation.

Comment: strike them back with samonella token!!!

Comment: now, jokes aside, if you put your worthless token inside a pool with USD or some other liquidity and your token can be minted easily of course people would extract your USDC / DAI liquidity, thats what markets are for, they will set fair price for your asset

Comment: @Nulik What do you mean by minted easily. If it has fixed supply how can anyone mint it?

Comment: @GajeelRedfox so how did these traders get your token then

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what's happening:

1. I'm almost sure there exists another exchange with a lower price for the pair, otherwise the arbitrage opportunity wouldn't exist.
2. The pair creation tx was enough to trigger those bots, as the tx is publicly visible in the mempool even before it's mined.
3. If you wanted protection from arbitrage bots, you could possibly lock the pair so that trading could only be done in one direction or the other, so that you would eliminate the arbitrage opportunity. As long as there is such opportunity, a bot would certainly take it.

Comment: Thanks dude. But how to lock the pair?

Comment: @GajeelRedfoxTake Sakeswap or any Uniswapv2 clone and just tweak the code to change the state of `unlocked` to lock trading https://github.com/Sakeswap/sakeswap-protocol/blob/master/contracts/sakeswap/SakeSwapPair.sol#L200

Comment: @GajeelRedfox This would lock the trading both ways. You could change the implementation to lock in one direction.

Comment: https://bscscan.com/token/0x8bCD0060cB8a1CdA0c7105E4946e592Aa79ed9cC

Comment: is locking pairs means locking liquidty?

Comment: @GajeelRedfox Yeah, so like for WETH-USDC pair you could lock trading so that you could only trade WETH for USDC and not back or vice-versa, or lock trading on both sides so no trading is possible.